# ¿Como llenar ArrayList antes de mostrar la vista? o algo similar

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-fragment, cardview

### En mi aplicación tengo lo siguiente

- Un `RecyclerView` que se llenara con `CardView`
- Un `Fragment` que contiene el `RecyclerView`
- Un `ArrayList<>` que se llena con datos obtenidos desde **Firebase**

En el `onCreateView` realizo la instancia a **Firebease** y obtengo los datos desde la base de datos.

```
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    myRef.child("Paciente").addValueEventListener(this);
```

obtengo los datos en el siguiente método

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
            paciente.setContraseña(ds.child("contraseña").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setExpediente(ds.child("expediente").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setNombreCompleto(ds.child("nombreCompleto").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setTelefono(ds.child("telefono").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setDomicilio(ds.child("domicilio").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setFechaNacimiento(ds.child("fechaNacimiento").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setSexo(ds.child("sexo").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setKey(ds.getKey());
            arrayPacientes.add(paciente);
        }
    }
}
```

Para llenar mi `RecyclerView` tengo las siguientes lineas dentro del metodo `onCreateView`

```
Adapter_recycler_pacientes adapter_recycler_pacientes = new Adapter_recycler_pacientes(arrayPacientes);
recyclerViewPacientes.setAdapter(adapter_recycler_pacientes);
```

**Mi Adapter es el siguiente**

```
public class Adapter_recycler_pacientes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Paciente> arrayListPacientes;

public Adapter_recycler_pacientes(ArrayList<Paciente>arrayListPacientes){
    this.arrayListPacientes = arrayListPacientes;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View  view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_paciente,null,false);
    return new Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder(view) ;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter_recycler_pacientes.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.textViewNombre.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getNombreCompleto());
    myViewHolder.textViewDomicilio.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getNombreCompleto());
    myViewHolder.textViewPhone.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getNombreCompleto());
    myViewHolder.textViewFechaNacimiento.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getNombreCompleto());
    myViewHolder.textViewExpediente.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getNombreCompleto());
    myViewHolder.textViewKey.setText(arrayListPacientes.get(i).getKey());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListPacientes.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewNombre;
    TextView textViewFechaNacimiento;
    TextView textViewPhone;
    TextView textViewDomicilio;
    TextView textViewExpediente;
    TextView textViewKey;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre);
        textViewFechaNacimiento = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewFecha_nacimiento);
        textViewPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewPhone);
        textViewDomicilio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDomicilio);
        textViewExpediente = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewNumExpediente);
        textViewKey = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewKey);
    }

}
```

}

## Mi problema es

Que al momento de entrar al `Fragment` no me muestra ningún `CardView`

- Probé primero el método donde se llena el `ArrayList` a lo cual logro ver que si tiene datos.
- Lo segundo fue ver si antes de llegar al **Adapter** el `ArrayList` lleva datos, y descubro que no tiene ningún dato, al parecer tarda en llenarse o no se como funcione del todo.

**Por lo tanto creo que la razón por la que no se muestran los datos es por que el `ArrayList` tarda en llenarse.. a si que como podria llenarlo antes para poder mostrarlos en el `Fragment`**

Comment: Hola Richard, podrías poner el código del adapter

Comment: Otra cosa, y si llenas el adapter cuando termine el ciclo FOR?

Comment: @DanielSanchez ya agregue la clase adapter y por lo que entiendo se supone que el `ArrayList` se llena al momento de ejecutar la siguiente linea  `myRef.child("Paciente").addValueEventListener(this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llama a `notifyDataSetChanged` despúes del `for`

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
            paciente.setContraseña(ds.child("contraseña").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setExpediente(ds.child("expediente").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setNombreCompleto(ds.child("nombreCompleto").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setTelefono(ds.child("telefono").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setDomicilio(ds.child("domicilio").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setFechaNacimiento(ds.child("fechaNacimiento").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setSexo(ds.child("sexo").getValue().toString());
            paciente.setKey(ds.getKey());
            arrayPacientes.add(paciente);
        }
        adapter_recycler_pacientes.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

No olvides declarar `adapter_recycler_pacientes` `private` y fuera de `onCreateView`